# How do I alter images being added via IMCE CKEditor plugin?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, files

I just wanted to share my solution since I did not find any clue or different way of fixing the following problem:

Formerly, you could add a default class/ alter attributes of newly inserted images (or elements) in CKEditor. In Drupal 8, the `ckeditor.config.js` apparently was removed. Also, images added via IMCE CKEditor plugin are added via `insertHTML` and there seems not to be any way of manipulate the html string (despite listening to the `insertHtml` event) with the `htmlParser`.

How to alter the attributes of images added via imce in ckeditor?

Answer (score 1):

So, here is what I did, even if maybe its dirty.

Add a new module which attaches a custom library to forms:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/form';
}
```

In the `mymodule.libraries.yml`:

```
form:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/mymodule.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/ckeditor
    - ckeditor/drupal.ckeditor
    - imce/drupal.imce
    - imce/drupal.imce.ckeditor
```

And in the `mymodule.js` I pretty much just re-write the imce `sendto` function:

```
if (undefined !== CKEDITOR && CKEDITOR.imce.sendto) {
  CKEDITOR.imce.sendto = function (File, win) {
    var imce = win.imce;
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[imce.getQuery('ck_id')];
    if (editor) {
      var i;
      var text;
      var lines = [];
      var selection = imce.getSelection();
      var is_img = imce.getQuery('type') === 'image';
      for (i in selection) {
        if (!imce.owns(selection, i)) {
          continue;
        }
        File = selection[i];
        // Image
        if (is_img && File.width) {
          lines.push('<img class="img-responsive" src="' + File.getUrl() + '" />');
        }
        // Link
        else {
          // Use the selected text/image for the first link
          text = !lines.length && CKEDITOR.imce.getSelectedHtml(editor) || File.formatName();
          lines.push('<a href="' + File.getUrl() + '">' + text + '</a>');
        }
      }
      editor.insertHtml(lines.join('<br />'));
    }
    win.close();
  };
}
```

Hope this is helpful to somebody. And maybe there is another, better way of doing this - glad for any input!